# Asp.net Identity system to allow either username or email login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project where I have setup email confirmation, and forgotten password link to email and wish to customize the login structure to enable either username or password login. I changed the Account controller to enable username and a user was created successfully but can't login with the email address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible after digging my old identity framework project that accepts only username login and this that allows only email login I was able to combine the logic to give me what I wanted should anyone else wants to implement something similar here is my code

```
RegisterViewModel

<Required>
    <EmailAddress>
    <Display(Name:="Email")>
    Public Property Email As String
    <Required>
    <Display(Name:="User Name")>
    Public Property UserName As String

    <Required>
    <StringLength(100, ErrorMessage:="The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength:=6)>
    <DataType(DataType.Password)>
    <Display(Name:="Password")>
    Public Property Password As String

    <DataType(DataType.Password)>
    <Display(Name:="Confirm password")>
    <Compare("Password", ErrorMessage:="The password and confirmation password do not match.")>
    Public Property ConfirmPassword As String

LoginViewModel

<Required>
    <Display(Name:="Username or Email")>
    Public Property NameEmail As String

    <Required>
    <DataType(DataType.Password)>
    <Display(Name:="Password")>
    Public Property Password As String

    <Display(Name:="Remember me?")>
    Public Property RememberMe As Boolean
```

My `AccountController`, `Register` `Post` method

```
If ModelState.IsValid Then
            Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {
                .UserName = model.UserName,
                .Email = model.Email
            }
```

My `AccountController`, `Login` `Post` method

```
If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
            Return View(model)
        End If

        'Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
        Dim user = Await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.NameEmail)
        'If the user did not use his username search with his Email
        If user Is Nothing Then
            user = Await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.NameEmail)
            model.NameEmail = user.UserName
        End If
        If Not user Is Nothing Then

            If Not Await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id) Then
                ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on."
                Return View("Error")
            End If
        End If
        ' This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        ' To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
        Dim result = Await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.NameEmail, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout:=False)
        Select Case result
            Case SignInStatus.Success
                Return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)
            Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                Return View("Lockout")
            Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                Return RedirectToAction("SendCode", New With {
                    .ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                    .RememberMe = model.RememberMe
                })
            Case Else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.")
                Return View(model)
        End Select
```

Now I have my user to signup and confirm their email and login with either email or user name.